# AnyLogic Histogram of Options in OptionsList

Tags: histogram, anylogic

In my AnyLogic model there is a source where the parameter *agent.type* is one of Options from an *OptionList* called *Types*.

I want to create a Histogram that shows how many agents there are with each of the different possible Types.

I can do it by setting up a variable for each Type that increments the count() using a longwinded function, but I would prefer to use a dataset or histogram_data *optionsHistogram* using the OptionsList as the Horizontal axis value, and the count of the number of agents with that type as the Vertical axis value.

Is this possible, and what would you recommend as the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A histogram is used to plot the spread of one type of data.

If you want to plot the number of agents by type (and that is defined by an OptionList), you should use simple bar chart and use a statistic on your agent population as below:
[image]

You can then plot it in a bar chart using this setup:
[image]

PS: There is a lot of info about how those agent-pop statistics work in the help, worth a read.

Comment: Thank you Benjamin. The solution I came to is similar, but much less elegant than your proposal.

Comment: Hi @Pat if this helped, please mark the answer as "useful" (up-arrow next to the answer). This helps others find the answer easier in the future. Welcome to SOF :)

Comment: Hi Benjamin, I have ticked the accepted answer. Due to my low reputation stats my UpArrow is not visible, although it is there, and your generous help is much appreciated.